# Adding node to singly linked list not working properly

Tags: c, struct, singly-linked-list

I have a singly linked list struct and a local `Node` declared in main with my `addToList()` function, but every time `addToList()` executes it runs the case `(head == NULL)`. Even when I already added values to the list. I am sure there is a small bug in my code, I just can't find it.

```
typedef struct node{
  char* name;
  int groupSize;
  int status;
  struct node* next;
}Node;

void addToList(char* name, Node* head, int groupSize, int status){

if(head == NULL){
    head =(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    strcpy(head->name, name);
    head->groupSize = groupSize;
    head->status = status;
    head->next = NULL;
    printf("Name is %s\n\n", head->name);
}

else {
    printf("entered else\n");
    Node *tmp = head;
    if(tmp->next!=NULL){
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next  = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->next->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    strcpy(tmp->next->name, name);
    tmp->next->groupSize = groupSize;
    tmp->next->status = status;
    tmp->next->next = NULL;
  }
}

int main(){
  Node* head = NULL;

  //TESTNG SECTION

  addToList("Julio", head, 5, 7);

  addToList("Francisco", head, 5, 7);

  addToList("Jorge", head, 5, 7);

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your problem is the call by value of every C function call.
At the first call of `addToList()`, `head` of the `main()` points to `NULL`.

Inside the `addToList()` you change the **parameter** `head` to point to a newly allocated memory region. Unfortunately, by the time `addToList()` returns the scope of the **parameter** `head` does not exist any more. So the `head` variable at the main, has exactly the same value prior the `addToList()` call.

The solution to this problem would be the use of double pointer for the head, or return and assign at every call the head of the list. So because previous answer covered the one solution, I will provide the other.

```
Node* addToList(char* name, Node* head, int groupSize, int status){

    if(head == NULL){
        head =(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        head->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
        strcpy(head->name, name);
        head->groupSize = groupSize;
        head->status = status;
        head->next = NULL;
        printf("Name is %s\n\n", head->name);
    }

    else {
        printf("entered else\n");
        Node *tmp = head;
        if(tmp->next!=NULL){
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next  = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tmp->next->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
        strcpy(tmp->next->name, name);
        tmp->next->groupSize = groupSize;
        tmp->next->status = status;
        tmp->next->next = NULL;
     }  
     return head;
 }

int main(){
  Node* head = NULL;

  //TESTNG SECTION

  head = addToList("Julio", head, 5, 7);

  head = addToList("Francisco", head, 5, 7);

  head = addToList("Jorge", head, 5, 7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The head parameter will be initialized inside the function, you have to pass a pointer to a Node pointer :

```
void addToList(char* name, Node** head, int groupSize, int status);
```

Then :

```
*head =(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Explanations by Manos.

Comment: Thak you, after that I try doing this and is not working...

    *head->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*30);

Nerver mind, forgot the parenthesis, thank a lot!

Comment: I got this to work, could you please provide me with a more detailed explanation? I just really want to fully understand what is going on in the code.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few small problems that I see with your code.

First, I would use different names when passing in the head pointer. It might be confusing the compiler on where to look. Also, when you pass in a node pointer in addToList, you need to dereference it, so instead pass in Node**, and initialize a pointer within the method.

Second, in your addToList method, you have the following condition:

```
if(tmp->next!=NULL){
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

this will only work when you have 2 elements in your list. Instead, make it a while loop, like so:

```
while(tmp->next!=NULL){
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

This will correctly place the tmp pointer at the end of your list.

Hopefully this will fix some bugs,

Comment: The compiler does not get confused at all.

Comment: head is obviously being assigned incorrectly, does that mean we need to dereference within the method args?

Comment: It is not assigned incorrectly. It is just an effect of the call-by-value. The double pointer is just one solution. The other would be to return every time the head and assign it to a pointer. But your statement "might be confusing the compiler on where to look" is totally wrong.